# How does the Linux bridge works when a tap interface is connected

Tags: networking, network-bridge

Assume the following scenario:

```
brctl addbr BR0  
tunctl -t tap0  
brctl addif BRO tap0  
brctl addif BRO eth13  

ifconfig eth13 promisc up  
ifconfig tap0 promisc up  
ifconfig BR0 up
```

`eth13` is connected to a switch running STP and CDP

Since BR0 is a bridge shouldn't I see STP and CDP packets if I sniff tap0?

If I sniff BR0 (`tcpdump -i BR0`) I can see STP packets and CDP packets. 
Since this is a bridge all the packets received via one port should be sent out via all the other ports. Apparently this is not happening. Why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this question is simple. The tap interface will not receive traffic if nothing is attached to it. It shows up with `ifconfig` but nothing will come out of it if no program is attached to it.